# Serializer isKey is always false

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I wrote a trivial Kafka Serializer in order to check if Serializer --> configure method is able to tell me if currently key is being serialized or value.
Looking at interface definition that should be the case however when i use the code below isKey returns always false.

Can anyone tell me when configure method would be triggered?

Did I misunderstood isKey variable and it's actually indicating something different?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Headers;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class KafkaSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T> {

    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    protected JsonSchemaUtils jsonSchema = new JsonSchemaUtils();

    private boolean isKey;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        this.isKey = isKey;
        Serializer.super.configure(configs, isKey);
    }


    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
        Struct value = (Struct) data;
        System.out.println("isKey: " + isKey);
        ObjectNode schemaNode = jsonSchema.envelopeSchema(value);
        ObjectNode payloadNode = jsonSchema.envelopePayload(value);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectNode result = jsonSchema.envelope(schemaNode, payloadNode);
        try {
            out.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(result));
            byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
            out.close();
            return bytes;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new SerializationException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Headers headers, T data) {
        return Serializer.super.serialize(topic, headers, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        Serializer.super.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, did you set `key.serializer` to use this or `value.serializer`? Also, Kafka Streams comes with a Jackson based JSONSerde, or Confluent has JSONSchema one that works with their Registry. Also, you don't need the class name when using `super`

Answer (score 0):

It gets configured when `KafkaProducer` is created.

`true` is passed for `isKey` when the serializer is used for `key.serializer`

Source: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java#L367

Other than that, `T` is not guaranteed to be a Kafka Connect `Struct` (this class doesn't even have a binary representation itself). If you want to get Connect data from a String, use `StringConverter#toConnectData` (assuming you have JSON strings), and extend from `ByteArraySerializer` / `StringSerializer`... Interfaces have no `super` method that can be called.